# jQuery waypoints are not triggering correctly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I want to trigger some elements on my page with jQuery I scroll over to them. 
  Here's the HTML section (It contains some of the bootstrap code) :

```
  <section class="intro text-center section-padding" id="intro">
    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 wrapper wp1">
           <h1 class="arrow">We create the awesome</h1>
           <p>From Photo-Manupilations to flat designs, we do it awesomely!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

and the CSS part of this section :

```
.intro {

         background:#f3f5f8;
    }

    .intro .wrapper {
        padding:30px;
    }
```

and the JS part :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.wp1').waypoint(function() {
            $('.wp1').addClass('animated bounceInDown');
        }, {
            offset: '75%'
        });

});
```

ISSUE : It should `bounceInDown` when I scroll over to it but when I scroll over to the element, it's already there and after a sec it `bounceInDown`.
I've tried everything and tried to get the waypoints work on other elements, but they are already there and then they do the selected animation. 
I feel like I'm not explaining clearly so I included I video, illustrating the problem, hope this will help you. 
https://vimeo.com/118403013
Here is my code in action, you can see for your self [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FNFW/133/)

Comment: Are you trying to bind events depending on the scroll position of the browser window?

Comment: you can clearly see that the "We create the awesome" section is already there, and then after we scroll over to it, it do the animation.

Comment: @user1415571 no, exactly. I'm saying that it does the animation, it gets it alright. But the element shouldn't be already present there. I should bounceInDown after I scroll onto it. There would be nothing present at first .

Comment: @HaiderAliKhichi I never worked with `.waypoint` but have you explored the docs on how to do that stuff? Shouldn't your element be initially transparent, display:none; or something like that?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan well, I learned from their website. But, there's a template. I'm trying to mimic it, Check it out here : http://tympanus.net/Freebies/HalcyonDaysTemplate/
You can clearly see that their section is not there at first but when you scroll over to it, the text fadeInLeft That's what I'm trying to achieve